# my android app doesn't work even though there isn't an error

Tags: java, android, xml

I just wanna draw 100 randomly colored circles but i see a flash of circles for about a half second and it just disappears. I tried to fix it out on my own for 3 hours but couldn't find a clue. Tried constraint layout etc.. 
for you to note, there isn't an error.
what is the problem? i thought it was because of layout i don't understand completely at this moment. Help a little sheep coder

Android java code:

```
package com.example.seido.bubbledraw0408;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by seido on 2018-04-08.
 */

 public class BubbleView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private ArrayList<Bubble> bubbleList;
    private final int DELAY = 16;
    private Paint myPaint = new Paint(); //allow us to draw
    private Handler h; // like Timer in eclipse
    private int size = 30;

    public BubbleView(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
        super(context, attr);

        bubbleList = new ArrayList<Bubble>();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        h = new Handler();

    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){

        // just to test the ability to draw
        for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            bubbleList.add(new Bubble((int)(Math.random() * 300),
                    (int)(Math.random() * 400), 50));


        // draw all the bubbles on the screen
        for(Bubble bubble : bubbleList) {
            myPaint.setColor(bubble.color);
            c.drawOval(bubble.x, bubble.y,
                    bubble.x, bubble.y, myPaint);
        }
    }

    public class Bubble {

        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int size;
        public int MAX = 5;
        public int xSpeed;
        public int ySpeed;
        public int color;

        Bubble(int newX, int newY, int newSize){

            x = newX;
            y = newY;
            size = newSize;
            color = Color.argb((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256) ,
                    (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256));

            xSpeed = (int)(Math.random() * 2 * MAX - MAX);
            ySpeed = (int)(Math.random() * 2 * MAX - MAX);

            if(xSpeed == 0 || ySpeed == 0) {
                xSpeed = 1;
                ySpeed = 1;
            }

        }

        public void randomMotion() {

            x += xSpeed;
            y += ySpeed;

            if(x <= size/2 || x >= getWidth() - size/2) {
                xSpeed = -1 * xSpeed;
            }
            if(y <= size/2 || y >= getHeight() - size/2) {
                ySpeed = -1 * ySpeed;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom = "16dp"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="com.example.seido.bubbledraw0408.BubbleView">

<com.example.seido.bubbledraw0408.BubbleView
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you have no errors in logcat?

Comment: yes i have no errors in logcat..

Comment: please help me guru please

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried the provided code, and it worked as expected. Although, I think that following improvements may provide a solution to your situation.

Fist of all, it is not good to populate the list of bubbles in onDraw method - this method must do nothing but drawing. The initialization of the Bubble view must look as follows. Also, notice that I've override all the possible constructors of View, it is a better practice.

```
public BubbleView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    Initialize();
}

public BubbleView(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
    super(context, attr);

    Initialize();
}

public BubbleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    Initialize();
}

private void Initialize() {
    bubbleList = new ArrayList<Bubble>();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    h = new Handler();

    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        bubbleList.add(new Bubble((int)(Math.random() * 300),
                (int)(Math.random() * 400), 50));
}
```

Next, the onDraw will look as follows. Note, that in the code you provided  the left and right, top and bottom of oval are the same, so I have no idea how you were able to see anything.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
    Log.d("Let me", "draw");

    // draw all the bubbles on the screen
    for(Bubble bubble : bubbleList) {
        myPaint.setColor(bubble.color);
        c.drawOval(bubble.x, bubble.y,
                bubble.x + bubble.size, bubble.y + bubble.size, myPaint);
    }
}
```

This at least will make your code better. Also, are you calling onDraw multiple times? If so, this code will most likely fix your issue, as you will not adding 100 bubbles to array and drawing them all constantly.

Comment: I'm sincerely touched by your comment. thank you very much ! after my workday im going to try the code you offered. anyway I really love to code as an amateur because of people like you who are willing to help people

Comment: oh i just tried your code but it doesn't work either i see only blank black screen. can you show me your XML code ?